# Como hacer una Grafica con highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Quiero realizar una Grafica como la del siguiente link

> https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

```
 $(function () {  
  var data_trip = ["2011-01-22","2012-01-22","2013-01-22","2014-01-22","2015-01-22","2018-01-22"];
  var data_metros = [123,156,236,742,14,245];
    Highcharts.stockChart('barcinas', {
      chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Nº  Barcinas'      
      },

      xAxis: {
        categories: data_trip
      },

      yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        categories: [0],
        labels: {
          format: '{value}',
          style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
          }
        },

        title: {
          text: 'Nº Metros',
          style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
          }
        },

      }],

    tooltip: {
      shared: true
    },

    charBackgroundColor: {
      linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
      stops: [
        [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
        [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
      ]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Metros',
      type: 'line',
      yAxis: 0,
      color: {
        linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
        stops: [
          [0, '#0637e8'],
          [1, '#06bae8']
        ]
      },

      data: data_metros, //asignamos el valor a cada uno de los defectos (lineas)
      pointPadding: 0.1,
      pointPlacement: -0.2

    }],
      plotOptions: {
      column: {
        grouping: false,
        shadow: false,
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Tengo ese código y me hace la tabla el problema es que en el rango no me pone nada ¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que me pinta solamente

Comment: En el rango no te pone nada? Veo que tienes los bloques para los rangos y en la parte de abajo la regla marcando los mismos. A que te refieres exactamente?

Comment: tengo la variable `data_trip` que contiene las fechas y si vez en la imagen me pone datos que no deberían ademas de que la "barra de selección" no se mueve para nada, no se si me explico.¿? @Rostan

Answer (score 0):

Buen día

Hace como 1 o 2 años quise usar `categories` en `X` con el HighStock  pero no logre funcione, fijate hay [HighChart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo) y [HighStock](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo) la que estas usando (ya te comente el detalle de `categories`); contruye la estructura de las [series](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series%3Cline%3E.data) conforme es aceptado que cada punto en la gráfica debera estar representado por `X` y `Y` (usualmente `Fecha y Hora` y `Valor` respectivamente); para evitarte detalles en la presentación de `X` te sugiero uses en caso sea fecha el formato UTC.

Así como lo tienes separado en `data_trip` y `data_metros` no creo te de el resultado esperado.

Del link que proporcionas puedes probar con los datos que tienes para probar hasta que te resulte; veras que donde tienes `data: data_metros` debe ser una combinación de `data_trip` y `data_metros`.